# readTree Jackson cannot be resolved

Tags: java, json, jackson

So I'm quite new to `json` and `jackson` and I'm trying to use `readTree` but it keeps telling me

> "The type com.fasterxml.jackson.core.TreeNode cannot be resolved. It
>   is indirectly referenced from required .class files"

.
I'm using `jackson-databind-2.4.4.jar` and `jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar`, should I use another library instead?

```
    String response = "";
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
    JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(response);
```

Comment: You are using two Jackson versions from two very different generations; why is that? Why not only Jackson 2.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TreeNode` class is part of jackson-core. So you are probably missing the jackson-core JAR on your classpath. You can download it from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.4.4) for example.

Btw: This answer assumes that you are not using Maven to manage your dependencies, in which case the jackson-core dependency should be resolved automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve it by using proper [jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.2.3/jackson-core-2.2.3.jar)